# Si tengo esto en php/html y quiero que con javascript se aplique un cambio de atributo, ¿como lo hago?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

estoy aprendiendo a hacer plugins para wordpress, lo que quiero lograr es que con el input tome un setAttribute pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, les agradezco la ayuda y si tienen alguna duda pueden preguntar sin ningún problema, les dejo el código completo por si necesitan más información(He de mencionar que el plugin será gratuito y el código totalmente visible publicamente en GitHub)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Footerdit
Plugin URI: diweb.website
Description: Editing the footer text
Version: 1.0
Author: Liam Redes
Author URI: diweb.website
License: GPLv2
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'default_options');

function default_options()
{
  if (get_option('class') == false)
  {
    add_option('class', 'footer_text');
  }
}



function menu()
{
  $page = add_options_page('Footerdit', 'Footerdit', 'manage_options', 'Footerdit-conf', 'process_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'menu');

add_action('admin_post', 'save');

  function save()
  {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
      wp_die('Not Allowed');
    }

    check_admin_referrer('token');

    $code = sanitize_text_field($POST['code']);

    update_option('account', $code);

    wp_redirect(add_query_arg('page', 'Footerdit-conf', admin_url('option-general.php')));
    exit;
  }

  function process_page()
{
  $code = get_option('class');
  ?>

  <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Footerdit</h2>
    <form action="admin-post.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save">

      <?php wp_nonce_field('token'); ?>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the name class of your footer" value="<?php echo esc_html($code); ?>">
      <input type="text" id="f_text" placeholder="Enter the new Footer Text" value="<?php echo esc_html($code); ?>">
      <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save">
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'footer_script');

function footer_script()
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {'
   , ' var footer_text = document.getElementsByClassName("powered-by")[0];'
   , 'footer_text.setAttribute("id", "footer_text");'
   , 'footer_text_id = document.getElementById("footer_text");'
   . 'footer_text_id.innerHTML = "<p> Nuevo contenido </p>";'
   , '});'
   , '</script>';
} 

?>
```

Quiero que el value del input lo tome mediante javascript y al guardarlo se genere el nuevo innerHTML, eso es lo que estoy buscando, no duden en preguntar cualquier cosa(reitero) no hay ningún problema, gracias de ante mano

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128287/discussion-on-question-by-david-zaramoza-si-tengo-esto-en-php-html-y-quiero-que).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes escuchar los envíos del formulario, para ello haremos lo siguiente:

En el HTML daremos un id al botón del formulario.

### HTML

```
<form action="admin-post.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save">

  <?php wp_nonce_field('token'); ?>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the name class of your footer" value="<?php echo esc_html($code); ?>">
  <input type="text" id="f_text" placeholder="Enter the new Footer Text" value="<?php echo esc_html($code); ?>">
  <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save" id="btnSave">
</form>
```

### Javascript

Y en el código Javascript, escucharemos los clicks del botón y haremos el cambio que requieres.

La función `footer_script()` deberá ser modificada de este modo:

```
function footer_script()
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {'
   , 'var btnSave = document.getElementById("btnSave");'
   , 'btnSave.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   , 'e.preventDefault();'
   , 'var footer_text = document.getElementsByClassName("powered-by")[0];'
   , 'footer_text.setAttribute("id", "footer_text");'
   , 'var f_text = document.getElementById("f_text");'
   , 'footer_text_id = document.getElementById("footer_text");'
   , 'footer_text_id.innerHTML = f_text.value;'
   , '});'
   , '});'
   , '</script>';
}
```

### Post-Data

Debo decir que esta forma de escribir scripts como cadenas es poco elegante y poco práctica, además de exponer el código a errores. Cuando esto funcione considera usar otras herramientas de Wordpress como enquee para incluir archivos. Así, escribirías un archivo Javascript y lo conectarías con el plugin. Esto, además de permitir un código limpio, te permite re-utilizar tus scripts en otras partes y tener todo mejor ordenado.

Comment: De esta manera obtengo el value del input y reemplaza el innerHTML según lo que puse en el Input?

Comment: @DavidZaramoza de esa manera, cuando hagas click en el botón del formulario, debería hacerse el cambio, si es que no hay otros errores.

Comment: El cambio se hace, pero yo lo que busco es que se haga el cambio según lo puesto en el Input

Comment: @DavidZaramoza ¿cómo según lo puesto en el `input`? ¿Según lo puesto en cuál de los `input`?

Comment: En el segundo el que tiene la id="f_text"

Comment: Busco hacer algo como así: 'footer_text_id = document.getElementById("footer_text").innerHTML = "<p>" document.getElementById("f_text").value;"</p>"'

Comment: Sé que está mal, pero es un ejemplo

Comment: @DavidZaramoza simplemente tienes que alcanzar ese elemento por su id, haciendo esto: `var f_text = document.getElementById("f_text");` y luego usar la propiedad `value` del elemento para extraer su valor y ponerlo en el otro elemento: `footer_text_id.innerHTML = f_text.value;`. Revisa el código en la respuesta editada.

Comment: Ok, podrías hacerme el favor de las colocarlas con comillas simples(dobles)? por que me toma errores y no sé donde están cada unas

Comment: Ya lo solucioné eso, no importa, gracias, probaré el código ahora